# How do you unit-test a method with complex input-output

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

When you have a simple method, like for example sum(int x, int y), it is easy to write unit tests. You can check that method will sum correctly two sample integers, for example 2 + 3 should return 5, then you will check the same for some "extraordinary" numbers, for example negative values and zero. Each of these should be separate unit test, as a single unit test should contain single assert.

What do you do when you have a complex input-output? Take a Xml parser for example. You can have a single method parse(String xml) that receives the String and returns a Dom object. You can write separate tests that will check that certain text node is parsed correctly, that attributes are parsed OK, that child node belongs to parent etc. For all these I can write a simple input, for example

```
<root><child/></root>
```

that will be used to check parent-child relationships between nodes and so on for the rest of expectations.

Now, take a look at follwing Xml:

```
<root>
  <child1 attribute11="attribute 11 value" attribute12="attribute 12 value">Text 1</child1>
  <child2 attribute21="attribute 21 value" attribute22="attribute 22 value">Text 2</child2>
</root>
```

In order to check that method worked correctly, I need to check many complex conditions, like that attribute11 and attribute12 belong to element1, that Text 1 belongs to child1 etc. **I do not want to put more than one assert in my unit-test.** How can I accomplish that?

Comment: @vijaysylvester will certainly do so, I hope you don't mind letting others have they say as well before I accept the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need - is to check one aspect of the SUT (System Under Test) in separate test.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class XmlParserTest
    {
        [Test, ExpectedException(typeof(XmlException))]
        public void FailIfXmlIsNotWellFormed()
        {
            Parse("<doc>");
        }

        [Test]
        public void ParseShortTag()
        {
            var doc = Parse("<doc/>");

            Assert.That(doc.DocumentElement.Name, Is.EqualTo("doc"));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ParseFullTag()
        {
            var doc = Parse("<doc></doc>");

            Assert.That(doc.DocumentElement.Name, Is.EqualTo("doc"));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ParseInnerText()
        {
            var doc = Parse("<doc>Text 1</doc>");

            Assert.That(doc.DocumentElement.InnerText, Is.EqualTo("Text 1"));
        }

        [Test]
        public void AttributesAreEmptyifThereAreNoAttributes()
        {
            var doc = Parse("<doc></doc>");

            Assert.That(doc.DocumentElement.Attributes, Has.Count(0));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ParseAttribute()
        {
            var doc = Parse("<doc attribute11='attribute 11 value'></doc>");

            Assert.That(doc.DocumentElement.Attributes[0].Name, Is.EqualTo("attribute11"));
            Assert.That(doc.DocumentElement.Attributes[0].Value, Is.EqualTo("attribute 11 value"));
        }

        [Test]
        public void ChildNodesInnerTextAtFirstLevel()
        {
            var doc = Parse(@"<root>
              <child1>Text 1</child1>
              <child2>Text 2</child2>
            </root>");

            Assert.That(doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes, Has.Count(2));
            Assert.That(doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].InnerText, Is.EqualTo("Text 1"));
            Assert.That(doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[1].InnerText, Is.EqualTo("Text 2"));
        }

        // More tests 
        .....

        private XmlDocument Parse(string xml)
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            return doc;
        }
    }
```

Such approach gives lots of advantages:

1. Easy defect location - if
   something wrong with attribute
   parsing, then only tests on
   attributes will fail.
2. Small tests are always easier to understand

UPD: See what Gerard Meszaros (Author of xUnit Test Patterns book) says about topic: [xunitpatterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Principles%20of%20Test%20Automation.html)

> One possibly contentious aspect of
>   Verify One Condition per Test is what
>   we mean by "one condition". Some test
>   drivers insist on one assertion per
>   test. This insistence may be based on
>   using a Testcase Class per Fixture
>   organization of the Test Methods and
>   naming each test based on what the one
>   assertion is verifying(E.g.
>   AwaitingApprovalFlight.validApproverRequestShouldBeApproved.).
>   Having one assertion per test makes
>   such naming very easy but it does lead
>   to many more test methods if we have
>   to assert on many output fields. Of
>   course, we can often comply with this
>   interpretation by extracting a Custom
>   Assertion (page X) or Verification
>   Method (see Custom Assertion) that
>   allows us to reduce the multiple
>   assertion method calls into one.
>   Sometimes that makes the test more
>   readable but when it doesn't, I
>   wouldn't be too dogmatic about
>   insisting on a single assertion.

Comment: some of your tests are having multiple asserts and this was exactly the source of my concern. There are numerous disadvantages to having multiple asserts in single test case: you do not asserts folloiwng the failing will fail or not, can be difficult to understand what exactly is failing etc.

Comment: @Dan, Each test checks only one aspect of system behaviour, and this is sufficient granularity. I would suggest not to be so dogmatic. See what Gerard Meszaros (Author of xUnit Test Patterns book) says about topic (in my answer update)

Comment: sounds fine. I wonder though, aren't in that case tests with simple input aka. ParseShortTag redundant? To be more precise, Your ParseShortTag should probably be named: DocumentContainsElementNamedAsExpectedFromInputString, but should't such test be executed on complex input string as well?

Comment: Yep, why not? Write a test on every case which is suspicious for you. For this particular case the name would be ParseShortTagInSecondLevelOfXml and input would be "<root><level1><doc/></level1></root>" string.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple tests.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple tests. The same restrictions apply. You should test some normal operational cases, some failing cases, and some edge cases.

In the same way that you can presume that if sum(x, y) works for some values of x it will work with other values, you can presume that if an XML parser can parse a sequence of 2 nodes, it can also parse a sequence of 100 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on Ian's terse answer: make that bit of XML the setup, and have separate individual tests, each with their own assertion.  That way you're not duplicating the setup logic, but you still have fine-grained insight into what's wrong with your parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nunit Fluent Syntax

```
Assert.That( someString,
      Is.Not.Null
      .And.Not.Empty
      .And.EqualTo("foo")
      .And.Not.EqualTo("bar")
      .And.StartsWith("f"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar kind of requirement , where i wanted to have 1 Assert for various input sets. please chekout the link below , which i blogged .

[Writing better unit tests](http://apvijay.blogspot.com/2010/05/tips-for-writing-unit-test-cases.html)

This can be applied for your prob as well. Construct a factory class , that contains the logic for constructing 'complex' input sets . The unit test case has only one Assert.

Hope this helps.

Thanks ,
Vijay.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also use your own assertions (this is taken from your own question):

**attribute11 and attribute12 belong to element1**

`('attribute11 ', 'attribute12').belongsTo('element1');`

or

`('element1 attribute11').length`

The

BTW, this is similar to jQuery. You store this string in an complex graph repository. How would you unit test a very complex graph-connected database?